# stanford cs106a Bouncing Ball code questions

Tags: java, algorithm

I am new learner of public sources of stanford cs106a. 
I got stucked when I read handout BouncingBall,here below are the complete codes
I got from cs106a handout.

The question is, for `checkForCollision` method code that is bottom of this page,
why should the ball do the code `ball.move(0, -2 * diff)`, especially
execute the `-2 * diff`, I cannot understand this math code. Is it Ok for 
ball do the code `ball.move(0, -diff)`? what is the difference?
what is the bounce logic? anyone here could help me to understand this 
code, I am not good at math. Thank you so much

```
/*
 * File: BouncingBall.java
 *--------------------------
 * This program graphically simulates a bouncing ball
 */

import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class BouncingBall extends GraphicsProgram {

/** Size (diameter) of the ball */
private static final int DIAM_BALL = 30;

/** Amount Y velocity is increased each cycle
 * as result of gravity
 */
private static final double GRAVITY = 3;

/** Animation delay or pause time between call moves */
private static final int DELAY = 50;

/** Initial X and Y location of ball */
private static final double X_START = DIAM_BALL;
private static final double Y_START = 100;

/** X Velocity */
private static final double X_VEL = 5;

/** Amount Y Velocity is reduced when it bounces */
private static final double BOUNCE_REDUCE = 0.9;

/** Starting X and Y Velocities */
private doublexVel = X_VEL;
private doubleyVel = 0.0;

/* private instance variable */
private GOval ball;

public void run() {
    setup();

    // Simulation ends when ball goes off right hand
    // end of screen
    while (ball.getX() < getWidth()) {
        moveBall();
        checkForCollision();
        pause(DELAY);
    }

}

/** Create and place a ball */
private void setup() {
    ball = new GOval (X_START, Y_START, DIAM_BALL, DIAM_BALL);
    ball.setFilled(true);
    add(ball);
}

/** Update and move ball */
private void moveBall() {
    // increase yVelocity due to gravity
    yVel += GRAVITY;
    ball.move(xVel, yVel);
}

/** Determine if collision with floor, update velocities
 *  and location as appropriate
 */
private void checkForCollision() {
    if (ball.getY() > getHeight() - DIAM_BALL) {

        // change ball's Y velocity to now bounce upwards.
        yVel = -yVel * BOUNCE_REDUCE;

        // Assume bounce will move ball an amount above
        // the floor equal to the amount it would have dropped
        // below the floor
        double diff = ball.getY() - (getHeight() - DIAM_BALL);
        ball.move(0, -2 * diff);
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the `ball.move` is called, the ball has moved beyond the surface it's bouncing against.  So `-diff` would move it back to the surface, `-2 * diff` makes it bounce up.

Comment: is it OK for just do the ball.move(0, -diff) to put the ball back to the surface, because the ball will do the call moveBall() after pause(), after moveBall() called, that can bounce up the ball, correct? like below cycle:  

 while (ball.getX() < getWidth()) {
        moveBall();
        checkForCollision();
        pause(DELAY);
    }

Comment: I was trying to add codes to comments, but it was messed, not formatted, sorry, newer using stakoverflow

Comment: You could think of this as an Energy thing - if you just moved the ball back to the surface, you would be losing some of the height the ball should have had.  And the amount lost would be almost random, depending on how far the ball traveled below the surface.  (Indeed, the calculation should probably be `ball.move(0, -(1 + BOUNCE_REDUCE) * diff)`  because the bounce should be reduced )

Comment: Thank you, that is good point, for understanding this code,I think I may made a logic mistake, the ball is moving, checkForCollision, wait, moving again, checkForCollion, wait. When the ball hit the bottom, and fallen below the floor, we need to -differ to put ball back to the ground surface, and -2 * differ to get the ball bounced up the highest level.(is this correct understanding?)and called the pause method. The ball is gonna going down by calling moveBall() method, and then checkForCollision() again?

Comment: if yes, when the ball is going down, the start Y Velocity(yVel = -yVel * BOUNCE_REDUCE, yvel is instance variable, and call moveBall(), inside of moveBall(), yvel += gravity. Here, the yVel is getting wired now. 

and also, I just did experiment, I just put code ball.move(0, -diff) instead of ball.move(0, -2 * diff) for bouncing up.  it works very well. 

it confused me a lot, I found out my bouncing up logic was mess, it is really difficult for me to understand this whole process.